# Pygame not downloading

Tags: python, pygame

When I go to Pygame's download page and I click the MSI download it sends me to a white page for a split second but no files download, I've also tried the EXE downloader but nothing happens, I have Python installed already but nothing is happening, so what's the problem?

Comment: use pip via the terminal/command prompt. `pip install pygame`

Answer (score 0):

You pip, python package installer.

```
pip install pygame
```

Answer (score -1):

You use chrome right? That would be a chorme bug.
But even with another browser try this:

right click the link, copy the url and then paste it in your address bar. it should download the file.